# git push sporadically fails on Jenkins with "Device not configured" error

Tags: git, jenkins

We are using [Jenkins git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) to clone git repo, with credentials, before the build.

At the end of the build, if it is successful, we do git push:

```
BRANCH_TO_PUSH=${GIT_BRANCH/origin\//}
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/${BRANCH_TO_PUSH}
```

**Sporadically**, the push fails with the following output:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.example.net': Device not configured
```

How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue happens when the repo is configured to be cloned over HTTPS.
If it only happens sporadically, it means that git is configured to use credential helper to store the credentials at clone time.

However, [by default the cache is set to 900 seconds (15 minutes)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache). If your build takes longer than that, the push will fail.

To raise the cache TTL to 60 minutes run this on your Jenkins machine:

```
sudo su - jenkins
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```